# "Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger" error in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, debugging, ssms

I am trying to access a remote server using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

For some reason I am getting an error that says"Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger, could not connect to the Database Engine instance 'xx'. Make sure you have enabled the debugging firewall exception and are using a login that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role" every time I attempt to debug. However, I am able to see the data of the server in my object explorer.

At this point in time I have completely removed my windows firewall protection and am using a username and password that all my colleagues use, and it works for them.

I am also running the program as an administrator each time.

The server seems to be SQL Server 2008 R2.

Anything that I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The server version seems to be 10.50.1600 which according to http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.ca/ is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: In my experience, it has only ever been possible to run the debugger when logged in locally to the server that you are connecting to.

Comment: The problem was that I was pressing "Debug Statement" rather then "Execute Statement". When pressing the execute command everything worked as expected.